# Proof of unique solution of first order non-linear ODE - question ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As I want to solve my homework myself, so I'll describe it a bit more general:

> Given an ODE of the form$$y'=q(x)+p(x)y^6 ,\quad y(0)=y_0>0$$ proof that it has got an unique solution $y:[0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$.
>
> As a hint show that $0<y(x)\le Q(x)$ with $Q'(x)=q(x)$

For uniqueness we know picard-lindelöf.
But it seems a little bit complicated for me, as I can't solve the ODE, which isn't asked.

My attempt:

Let $f(x,y)=q(x)+p(x)y^6$ be continous on $$D=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : |x| \le a,|y-y_0|\le b\, a,b\in\Bbb R\}$$

Further
$$|f(x,y)-f(x,y')|=|p(x)||y^6-(y')^6| \le|y^6-(y')^6|$$, as $|p(x)|\le1$

I just don't know how to continue,how to show and use the hint :((, some advice would be great:

Comment: You can't just assert continuity of $f(x,y)$, you have to show that it IS continuous in that rectangle to assert uniqueness in the rectangle. We cannot do a whole lot with that without knowing some things about $q(x)$ and $p(x)$, as you've written nothing about them. For example, you cite $|p(x)| \leq 1$ without ever stating it in your hypothesis. I feel like some details are amiss.

Comment: @DaveNine: Here $p(x)=-1$ and $q(x)=3x^2$